# JSP client for Axis2 web service in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jsp, apache-axis, tomcat5.5

I am new to web services and have managed to convert an Axis1 web service to Axis2.  I can get data back from it using the Web Service Explorer with Eclipse.  I am using Eclipse 3.6.1, Tomcat 5.5, and Windows XP.  Problem is I am missing the JSP client to test with.

When you generate a web service using Eclipse and Axis 1, you get the generic 3-frame JSP test client with the methods on the left, input and results on the right.  Can't seem to get this to happen with Axis 2.  I have tried the Dynamic Web Project, Web Service, Web Service Client, and Axis2 CodeGen wizards in Eclipse, in various combinations, and all I get is a xxxCallbackHandler.java and xxxStub.java.  I am able to test using the Web Service Explorer, but I need the JSP client because we have folks doing testing who aren't developers and don't have Eclipse.

I tried converting the JSP test client from the old Axis 1 service.  This didn't go well because there are lots of references to org.apache.axis stuff that isn't part of Axis 2 (or at least reorganized to the point I couldn't find it).

Any suggestions on how to get a JSP client to generate or, if I need to build one, maybe an example?  I have Googled to the point where every search I do for jsp, client, webservice, and eclipse, all the results come back purple.  Somebody's got to have had this problem before...

Answer (score 1):

If you need  some UI tool for testing, I do not necessarily need JSP generated by Axis but can use some tools like [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

This is their guide how to do functional testing with SoapUI: http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/functional-testing.html

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem using Eclipse Helios and Indigo on a Win 2003 server. The issue seems to be a bug, see here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=341525.

I am using the Web Services>Create Client wizard to do my testing by letting Eclipse test the client with it's automatically generated JSPs at the end of the wizard.